Probation for converts?
I heard that a convert to Judaism who wants to become a rabbi or a cantor or even a Jewish day school teacher has to wait five years after the conversion, presumably to make sure the conversion "takes".  I never heard of a probationary period for converts, for any purpose.  Is this true?

Not sure about what you heard about. I think once geirus is complete, there is no turning back, convert is Jewish. I do know that a bais din might hold back a certifcate of geirus for some reasons which can cause the convert to be questioned when they try t use there Jewish status, i.e. marry another Jew. Maybe some places do this for a probationary preiod.

The wait is, presumably, not to certify that the convert is Jewish (he is), but to make sure he doesn't backtrack (which he can do and still be Jewish).

That is not a halacha, although it might be the practice of someone out there.

@N.T. -- More than that.  Doesn't halacha say that converts must not be treated differently from born Jews?

@MauriceMizrahi Not quite. There is a mitzvah to love the convert which indicates special treatment. On the other hand, there are certain positions not given to converts. See https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

There's surely some time needed to "fill your guts with Shas and Poskim", so probably it is not about observance but proficiency in Jewish sources and thinking.
